# SonataAdmin $showMapper

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I try to add own content (html) to showMapper.

In listMapper I can use template. How to do this in showMapper?

This doesn`t work:

```
 $showMapper->add('content', 'html', [
     'template' => 'whatever',
     'data'=>'test'           
 ])
```